# Python replace multiple substrings in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, regex, string

I have a text: "{name} likes {post}". I fetch data according to the values inside {} from db. Then I get values coming inside an Array, like ["John", "515335"] for one piece of data.

I don't know how many variables I will get inside the string. Would be 1 or 3 too. ( But the count of content to be replaced and values will be same)

So what would be the best way to replace the values in this string please?

I tried:

```
for i in range(len(subContentArr)):
              content = re.sub(subContentArr[i], valuesArr[i], content, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

But I get `local variable 'content' referenced before assignment` . (Content is the text I get with curly braces)

Expected output: "John likes 515335"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `a` and `b` are your inputs from your database, you can create your wanted output `d` like this:

```py
import re

a = "{name} likes {post}"
b = ['John', '515335']

c = re.sub(r'\{[^}]+\}', '{}', a)

d = c.format(*b)
```

Basically `c` will be a modified version of your input string which will simplify the placeholders to `{}` on which we then can use `.format()` to replace the placeholders with the values in the same order.